# Combine Framework stream transformation ['a','b','c'] -> 'a' then 'b' then 'c'

Tags: swift, combine

Simple question, but struggling a while with it.

I have a web request, where I fetch an array of strings: `['a','b','c']`

So to speak I have a `CurrentValueSubject` of `['a','b','c']`. I would like to create a downstream, where the elements then go one by one, how to achieve that?

Combine Framework stream transformation `['a','b','c']` -> `'a'` then `'b'` then `'c'`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how you got from "a web request" to a `CurrentValueSubject`. Wouldn't you have a `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` or something like that instead? Or did you not use Combine to do the web request?

Comment: i did not use URLSession, some other library on behind is doing this, I just receive an array of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to create a publisher that, for each element that the upstream publisher publishes, transform the element to a publisher and publish what that publisher publishes instead.

Suppose `cvs` is a `CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>`, you can get a publisher that publishes each string of the array that `cvs` publishes by doing:

```
cvs.flatMap(\.publisher)
```

Note that `\.publisher` here refers to the `publisher` property on sequences, which is a publisher that publishes each element separately.

Comment: flatmap would give him a publisher as a result but he can use 'map' instead to just get the values.

Comment: @AliMomeni I'm not sure what you are talking about, but I would just get the `value` of the current value subject.

Comment: thanks, I ended up with
newMessages.flatMap{entities -> AnyPublisher<JSON,Error> in
            Publishers.Sequence(sequence: entities).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .map{ message in ..... }

Comment: @Ivan that works too, if you want an `AnyPublisher`.